# $routeParams returning an empty object

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

an angular application.

```
var self = this;
angular.module("myForm", ["ngRoute"])
     .controller("Controller", ["$scope", "$routeParams", function($scope, $routeParams){self.controller($scope, $routeParams)}]);

angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("form"), ["myForm"]);
```

It's returning an empty object, `{}`

while the url is

```
http://localhost:3000/admin/event/form/?id=1
```

Controller:

```
controller: function($scope, $routeParams) {
    console.log($routeParams);
},
```

**Edit**

I read to add ng-view. I did but same problem

```
<span ng-view></span>
```

The route is not really changing, I want to read this value on page load only.

Comment: You need to define a route to use routeParams https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams

Comment: how to define for a queryString, I'm new to this, further the routes are not changing, i want to access existing query string value at page load/end of `bootstrap`

Answer (score 1):

The pattern ?id=1 in your url is not the correct way of passing route params. And to support route params, one should define the routes and the params which it supports. Route is defined in config block as ([referred example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#example) from angular docs):

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider
   .when('/Book/:bookId', {
    templateUrl: 'book.html',
    controller: 'BookController',
    resolve: {
      // I will cause a 1 second delay
      delay: function($q, $timeout) {
        var delay = $q.defer();
        $timeout(delay.resolve, 1000);
        return delay.promise;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

To access the route and pass param to the above defined route, one must construct the url as:

<protocol><domain prefix>/Book/123

So /Book is your route and 123 is the param value of bookId. in your $routeParams it is available as $routeParams.bookId